# How to call a WCF method asynchronously from MVC4 WebAPI

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await, twilio

I am new to the WebApi, .Net world and am totally confused with all the information available as to what approach I should take. I have created a WebService using MVC4 WebApi that Twilio calls when a text message is received. I need to respond to this text message. I am consuming a WCF method which is currently being called synchronously. Since it is possible that my process can take longer than 3-5 seconds to process a reply to the text message the connection to Twilio gets disconnected due to timeout. So I am looking for ways to call this WCF method asynchronously. 
My question is to call the WCF method (I am calling the WCF using a Object Factory and using)
do I need to update the contract to say Async? I am little confused on that.

BTW my Web Service is in IIS7 and am using .Net4.5 framework and MVC4 WebApi .

My code is somewhat like this: So I would like to call the SendSms part asynchronously. How do I do that? Can I simply use Task.Run Async and Await?

```
 using Twilio.Mvc;
 using Twilio.TwiML.Mvc;
 using Twilio.TwiML;


public class SmsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]SmsRequest smsReq)
    {
            var response = new Twilio.TwiML.TwilioResponse();
            //validation checks..

            try
            {

                -- call to WCF to get the List of sms to be sent 
                if ((txtMessageResponse != null) && (txtMessageResponse.SmsMessageInfo.Count > 0))
                {
                    _smsStagingList = txtMessageResponse.SmsMessageInfo;
                    foreach (TextMessageStaging prepareTextMessageResponse in _smsStagingList)
                    {
                        smsDTO textMessageItems = new smsDTO();
                        textMessageItems.PhoneNumber = prepareTextMessageResponse.PhoneNumber;
                        textMessageItems.SmsMessage = prepareTextMessageResponse.SmsMessageBody;

                        isTxtMessageSent = SendSms(textMessageItems);

                        //If the messages were sent then no need to set the flag to be updated 
                        if (isTxtMessageSent)
                        {
                            txtMessageStatusToBeUpdated = false;
                        }
                    }
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, twilioResponse.Element);
                }
                else
                {
                    //send error response
                }
            catch (Exception msgProcessingError)
            {
              //send error response again as processing error
            }
            finally
            {
             //set the outbound flag in the table
            }
     }


    private bool SendSms(smsDTO textMessageItems)
    {
        bool isTxtMessageSent = false;
        PushMessageRequest txtMessageRequest = new PushMessageRequest();
        PushMessageResponse txtMessageResponse = null;
        txtMessageRequest.SmsMessageInfo = new SendTextMessage(); //instantiate the dto

        txtMessageRequest.SmsMessageInfo.ToPhone = textMessageItems.PhoneNumber;
        txtMessageRequest.SmsMessageInfo.TextMessage = textMessageItems.SmsMessage;
        try
        {
            using (ITextService textService = ObjectFactory.SendSmsMessage())
            {
                txtMessageResponse = textService.SendSmsMessage(txtMessageRequest);
            }

            isTxtMessageSent = txtMessageResponse.IsSuccessful;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isTxtMessageSent = false;
        }      
        return isTxtMessageSent;
    }
```

Comment: Couple of clarifying questions.  Did you using ASP.NET Web API or WCF to create your service?  Also, is there a specific method you are calling inside of your service that you know could be long running?

Comment: @DevinRader - I am using ASP.NET Web API to create the service. But inside my HTTP post I have implemented a method that resides inside a WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

OK, so you have a Web API method in which you call a WCF method that is potentially long running.  There are two problems to solve here:

1. How do you call the WCF method in a way that does not block the Web API method from returning a response
2. How do you get Twilio to wait until the WCF method has finished

I wrote a [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/09/long-running-tasks-in-ivr-systems.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) a while ago that shows you how to create an indefinite wait loop in an IVR by leveraging .NET's [Task Parallel library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [loop](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#attributes-loop?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) attribute on Twilios [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) verb.

The gist of the post is that you can use the TPL's [StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to start the long running WCF method on a new thread.  This lets ASP.NET continue and lets you return some TwiML so Twilio does not end the call.  Then you pair that with a [continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which lets you know when the WCF service request is done and you can signal back to Twilio using the REST API to [redirect the in-progress call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state#example-1?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) to a new set of TwiML instructions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice blog post. But the blog shows how to do when a caller is waiting for the caller to reply. In my case it is an SMS. So what TwiML message can I return? Also please note that I am actually not planning to return anything via TwiML but am gonna use the Twilio Rest API to send out the message as reply i.e. outgoing message. This is because for an incoming text it is possible that I have more than 10 sms messages to be sent as a reply and this is a limitation in TwiML api.

Comment: Basically I think I need something that can fire and forget unless we have another way of telling twilio to wait to get the reply. I am not sure along with SMS verb what other verbs we can use. As I believe we cannot use redirect along with Sms Verb.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Well in that case you you can't do it via a pure TwiML response.  But you can do it by changing the code from the post a little bit.  First, since this is an SMS we are talking about you don't need to return anything from the ASP.NET method.  Second, in the Continuation, instead of modifying the call via the API you  need to use the REST API to send your reply SMS.  Hope that helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do. But wanted to send it via the Asynchronous method because it looks like when a message is being sent via Twilio Rest API it takes about 1 sec to send each text message out. So if I have around 15-20 messages to be sent out then it takes more time and my connection with Twilio times out. So want to call the Twilio Rest Api for sending out messages asynchronously. Did this make sense? So my question is to send it asynchronously what method should I use that can do the same as Fire and Forget?

Comment: Little confused with your comment "instead of modifying the call via the API you need to use the REST API to send your reply SMS" - Did you mean by the fallback reply or the actual reply?